# datatype of anonymous function vs named function in scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am curious to understand the datatype of anonymous function in Scala(2.13.8).

While reading Functional programming in Scala, I see below code

```
scala> (x:Int,y:Int)=> x<y
```

As per the book, the output should be like below

```
res3: (Int,Int)=> Boolean = <Function2>
```

But what I get is

```
val res3: (Int, Int) => Boolean = $Lambda$883/1341083542@7c871ce4
```

Below code also does not shows Function2 as type in result

```
scala> val lessThan = (x:Int,y:Int)=> x<y
val lessThan: (Int, Int) => Boolean = $Lambda$841/566447096@559e3f67
```

However, When I write the below code, I can see Function2 object is created

```
scala> val lessThan2 = new Function2[Int,Int,Boolean] {
     | def apply(a:Int, b:Int)= a<b }
val lessThan2: (Int, Int) => Boolean = <function2>
```

My question is why in an anonymous function, I don't see datatype as Function2(as per the book page number 24, I should have seen it

Comment: It's just how lambdas are implemeted: each creates its own anonymous class. They are all subclasses of `Function2` though: try `res3.isInstanceOf[Function2[_,_,_]]`, so, it is inconsequential.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Language defines some syntactic sugar which REPL follows:

- instead of `Tuple2(1, 2)` you can just do `(1, 2)`
- same for `Tulple3`, `Tuple4`, etc
- instead of `Function1[Int, String]` you can use `Int => String`
- same for `Function2`, `Function3`, ...

In your example there is also the thing that REPL often shows results int the form

```
resN: Type: value as seen by toString
```

Thing is, functions cannot have a reasonable `toString` representation, so it prints the default JVM `toString`: name of the class + the instance address. Author of the book simply used `<function2>` as a placeholder for this seemingly random String which changes for every new function, because it is inconsequential.

Comment: Not quite. `$Lambda$883/1341083542` is the actual name of a class. Also, functions certainly _can_ have a sensible string representation (for some definition of "sensible" at least): as op shows `new Function2[String,String,Boolean] { def apply(x: String, y: String) = true; }.toString` returns `<function2>`, which I am sure some would consider more sensible than `$Lambda$883/1341083542@7c871ce4` (though, personally I would argue that the latter is more informative).

Comment: But that's what I said. `$Lambda$883/1341083542@7c871ce4` - `$Lambda$883/1341083542` - name of the class, `@` - separator, `7c871ce4` - hash of the address of the instance. As for whether toString of functions should be overridden... functions cannot be compared, so it'd prefer `toString` to reflect that, sutuation where `<function2> != <function2>` in one case and `<function2> == <function2>`in another would be confusing to debug.

Comment: I meant: in practice functions cannot be compared in other way than comparing references.

Comment: On Scala 2.11 and earlier, it really did print e.g. `<function2>`. It's because Scala 2.12 changed to using LambdaMetaFactory, just as Java 8 does, that the `toString` changed. And the book (the first edition) was written well before Scala 2.12 existed.

Comment: Thank you all for sharing the knowledge; it's really helpful. what I don't understand is why this question is rated with now -2 :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just to more concretely put what @Dima already hit the nail on the head with:

This is simply a product of the `toString` implementation of that `Lambda` instance.

```scala
// Note: `(Int, Int) => Boolean` is syntactic sugar for `Function2[Int, Int, Boolean]`

// lessThan: Function2[Int, Int, Boolean]
val lessThan: (Int, Int) => Boolean = { ( x, y ) => x < y }
// $Lambda$16/0x0000000800bb3040@edf4efb

// lessThan.isInstanceOf[Function2[Int, Int, Boolean]]
lessThan.isInstanceOf[(Int, Int) => Boolean]
// True
```

That is to say the output *looks* slightly different, but the `Lambda` instance you created ***is*** a `sub-class` of `Function2`